# How to resolve cannot find -lcrypt in Cygwin?

Tags: ruby, windows, cygwin, jekyll

I'm trying to install Jekyll using Cygwin. I navigate to my project directory and run:

```
gem install jekyll
```

There were several errors but nothing that I couldn't solve by installing the appropriate package but there's an error that I'm currently stuck with:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
  ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
      ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150401-7872-17w9ed4.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
rm -f
rm -f stemmer.so  *.o  *.bak mkmf.log .*.time

make "DESTDIR="
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I.    -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration    -o porter.o -c porter.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I.    -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration    -o porter_wrap.o -c porter_wrap.c
rm -f stemmer.so
gcc -shared -o stemmer.so porter.o porter_wrap.o -L. -L/usr/lib -L. -fstack-protector -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import    -lruby200  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:232: recipe for target 'stemmer.so' failed
make: *** [stemmer.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/<user>/.gem/ruby/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/<user>/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-cygwin/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/gem_make.out
```

Am I missing something?

I was following these tutorials:

- http://nathanielstory.com/2013/12/28/jekyll-on-windows-with-cygwin.html
- http://matt.scharley.me/2012/03/10/windows-cygwin-and-jekyll.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install package libcrypt-devel

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/9ce35bc6de/misc/install-jekyll.sh#L2)